# What happens when you chmod 600 /etc/passwd?

Tags: linux

Yes, yes I know there are no real passwords or even hashes in that file on modern systems.  However, I am quite curious if this is a good, easy way to totally lock down a system from everyone and what would break first.  I don't have a spare system, but it sure sounds like a fun experiment.  Has anyone tried this?

Comment: This is pretty interesting from the point of view where you might want to build a system where your users are unable to lookup the usernames of other users.

Comment: And according to pacey (below) also unable to lookup their own names as well!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just for you I tried it :-)

Any user will be able to login like normal. This is because login runs with root privileges. After being logged in the user won't have access to `/etc/passwd` which might cause problems with userland applications.

The first thing you might notice is that the shell cannot read your username which produce a prompt like

```
I have no name!@vs245042:~$
```

Comment: +1 just for trying it for me.  I'm surprised that your system wasn't totally borked.  Does it really say "I have no name!" or are you just paraphrasing?  Which distro/version did you try?

Comment: I tried this on a Debian 4.0 machine with bash as login shell. It is not paraphrased it's copied from terminal.

Comment: Also, ls will only show UID and GID in numeric form.  ~<username> won't expand either.

Comment: Wow.  If you didn't know that someone did a chmod, how would you ever figure out what happened?

Answer (score 5):

Setup an auditctl on /etc/passwd and see what tries to access it:
`auditctl -w /etc/passwd -p war`

Then afterwards analyse the output of:
`ausearch -f /etc/passwd`

See what's trying to access it, if it's all root processes then you're fine.

Comment: That's a cool idea.  Is there a way to config `auditctl` to only log non-root users?